# Dynamic CollectionProperty In Blender

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

With the given sample of CollectionProperty from blender API page, we can have a collection of `SceneSettingItem` which stores a 'name' in `StringProperty` and a 'value' in `IntProperty`.

```py
import bpy
class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test Property", default="Unknown")
    value: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Test Property", default=22)
bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)
bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)
my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.name = "Spam"
my_item.value = 1000
# ....
for my_item in bpy.context.scene.my_settings:
    print(my_item.name, my_item.value)
```

But Can we make it 'dynamic', so we can store something other than `IntProperty` in 'value', for example 'BoolProperty', is that possible in Blender Python?

To be more clear, I wish to store a Collection in material object, and every entry has a name, type and a value, the type of value can be `IntProperty`, `BoolProperty` or `FloatProperty`, and every material object holds different Collection Entries.

Comment: I don't think this is possible (though I would *love* to be corrected). The (messy) solution I have used in the past is to add separate properties for each type (`StringProperty`, `IntProperty` etc.) and then have another `StringProperty`, called `property_type`, which tells me which property to access. E.g. `property_type` might be `"string"` so I access the `StringProperty` or `property_type` might be `"int"` so I access the `IntProperty`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The solution I'm currently using is generating a specific `setting` class for different 'config' dynamically. It solved my problem almost perfectly.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should add it in the answer box below so other people can benefit from it.